# Do I need a visa to enter Russia if I have dual citizenship to two countries (one doesn't and other does)

Tags: visas, russia

So, I have citizenship to two countries, one being the USA which requires a visa. I am currently living in another country of which I also have citizenship which does not require a visa. I would prefer not to waste my time and work going to the consulate just for a question.

I know I can enter Russia on the passport I have in this country but am I required by law to disclose my US citizenship? They would be able to tell that I am not a natural citizen of this country without the visa given that my English and accent will be as if I just arrived from the USA.

Comment: As a side note, many, if not most, non-native English speakers "sound American" so I don't think you will sound too unusual :)

Comment: @josh to an American ear, very few non-native English speakers sound American, if any.

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt there will be many American's working at Russia's border control.

Comment: My point is, if Gregorsky provides a valid passport for vista free entry, an American sounding English speaking accent will not likely prompt the question of "Are you American?".

Comment: @josh I don't think any native English speaker would think that non-native speakers generally "sound American", so it would be strange if non-native speakers think they do. Especially since non-native speakers don't seem to have a hard time distinguishing British accents from American ones.

Comment: @DavidRicherby as a native English speaker I can often tell how, or where a non-native learnt to speak English. E.g. many Dutch people have an American twang to there English speaking voice because, I have been told, they watch a lot of American TV.

Answer (score 7):

Even if you had to disclose your US citizenship (which you don't), it won't make you ineligible for visa-free entry with your other passport. Why would it?

Citizenship is not a taint, as in, you are "tainted" with US citizenship and therefore require a visa.
Citizenship is a grant, as in, if you're granted "some country" citizenship you don't require a visa.

I know that some Middle Eastern states see citizenship as a taint vs. Israel, but this is not the case generally and this isn't the case with Russia.

Comment: While this is true as a general rule, and I suppose it probably is also true in this specific case, it isn't universally true.  A country can make a rule that citizens of country X require a visa regardless of other citizenships.  One country that has made such a rule is the US.

Comment: "Why would it?" Why _wouldn't_ it? If citizens of country X require a visa and citizens of country Y don't, it would make just as much sense for either one could take priority for X-Y dual nationals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby For starters, there's a solid, legally binding, proof of first citizenship at immigration booth, but there's no proof of dual nationality. If there's a country with which you have bilateral agreement to accept each other's citizens without visa, and then you don't let a person with their passport in for handwavy reasons, that's a transgression of agreement.

Comment: "Even if you had to disclose your US citizenship (which you don't)" Incorrect! Russia specifically has reporting requirements and it is a [criminal offense](http://intermarkrelocation.ru/about/news/notification-on-dual-citizenship-for-russian-nationals/) to knowingly conceal dual citizenship.

Comment: @user71659 It's a criminal offense *for Russians* to knowingly conceal dual citizenship -- this is not the same at all as requiring visitors to.

Comment: @jpatokal I agree. I interpreted the OP's statement that "I know I can enter Russia on the passport I have in this country" as this=Russia.

Comment: As a rule, when entering a country, you should always use this contry's passport if you have citizenship. Not honoring it may lead to problems in many locales.